# avoid calling render in sinatra

Tags: sinatra, view

how can I have sinatra by default try to render a file if it exists?
so I don't have to type :

```
get "/file" do
  erb "file"
end
```

I want it by default to try to render "file"

Answer (score 0):

If you want this sort of thing, just use a named parameter in your route:

```
get "/:name" do
  erb "#{params[:name]}"
end
```

See [Sinatra: README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes) for mor

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, i don't want to type erb "params[:name]" in every action.  I want to define it once and have it render appropriately.

Comment: You don't have to type this for every action (talking REST here?). This takes whatever is in the "action" spot, and searches for a file with that name. Either that or your question is not clear to me. Give an example of the code duplication you're worried about.

Comment: get "foo" do
  
end ;    get "bar" do
  
end